# Como puedo remplazar una tabla con el dblink en postgres

Tags: postgresql

Tengo que tomar informacion de un servidor y traerlo a otro, por lo cual primero estoy haciendo pruebas en un servidor jalando tablas de diferentes bases de datos, pero el problema esta en que la informacion se me duplica cada vez que ejecuto la funcion dblink.

¿como podria hacer que esa informacion solo se remplace sin que se duplique ?

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dblink_test()
      RETURNS void AS
    $BODY$


    declare 
     cRpta varchar;

    begin
     cRpta := (select dblink_connect('myconn','hostaddr=192.168.1.7 port=5432 dbname=db1 user=postgres password=AIMSA') ) ;
     raise notice '%',cRpta;

     insert into prueba2 (id,username )
     select * from dblink( 
      'myconn' ,
      'select id, username  from public.prueba1' )  
       as (id integer,username character varying );
     perform dblink_disconnect('myconn');
     --  select dblink_disconnect('myconn');

    end;
    $BODY$
      LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE
      COST 100;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Te sugiero que compartas el código como texto, junto a los errores que te genera el probar ese código. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: ¿Por qué usas esa función dblink_xxx en vez de usar foreign tables (que son más amigables en postgresql)?   Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Soy nuevo en postgres y apenas estoy entrando a este mundo de bases de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que analices los [FDW](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html) como comenta @Alfabravo, y lo combines con [`INSERT ... ON CONFLICT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html) o si tienes una version 15 o superior de PostgreSQL [`MERGE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-merge.html)